# Laptop started to crash on low memory conditions

Tags: windows, hard-drive, memory, ssd, bsod

I have a Lenovo T420s that has recently been freezing and then crashing with a blue screen (Windows 7).

It has 8GB RAM and a SSD hard disk. I frequently max out memory so hitting the pagefile a lot.

It didn't use to affect anything except to slow down things somewhat. In the past month Windows has been incredibly sensitive to low memory, crashing chrome and firefox whenever I overload it. It also occasionally bluescreens reporting something related to the hard disk, ...

**Blue screen crash after low memory conditions:**
[image: blue screen crash after low memory conditions]

**On restart I get this message each time, rebooting again always works OK:**
[image: POST message after bluescreen and reboot]

I also see some critical errors related to in the Window sEvent Log stating:

```
The device, \Device\Ide\iaStor0, did not respond within the timeout period.
```

My best guess is that it's the hard disk or controller failing and so when there's heavy swapping it's hitting the pagefile and hard disk failures are crashing my system, and causing Windows to scream on low memory in recent weeks.

So is it likely to be the hard disk? I thought if SSDs hard disks have a bad area they tend to mark it as bad and so the pagefile shouldn't be using bad parts.

Could it be the hard disk controller (essentially the motherboard) instead and I'd be wasting money buying a new hard disk?

Comment: If adding more RAM is not an option, you may try to revert back to stock MS AHCI driver to see if it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should run windows recovery disk and if you can preform a `clean install`. I am guessing it is a problem with windows which is causing problems with Hard drive.

Also make sure your drivers are all up to date and try and increase your RAM if you can.